# SUM all returned values from the CASE clause statement

Tags: sql-server, sum, case, distinct, common-table-expression

I have the following query. And need to sum all returned by the query "distinct case" values withing a row populated in another column "TotalDepartmentsCount"

```
;WITH CTE
     AS 
     (
     Select t.ID As [CTE_ID]
           ,count(distinct case when e.Department='M' then t.ID else null end) as M_Marketing
           ,count(distinct case when e.Department='S' then t.ID else null end) as S_Sales   
           ,count(distinct case when e.Department='U' then t.ID else null end) as U_Utilization    
           ,count(distinct case when e.Department=' ' then t.ID else null end) as No_NoDepartment
        From dbo.Table t (nolock) 
            Left Join dbo.ClearedEmployee ce (nolock) ON t.ID = ce.building_fk
                 Join dbo.Employee e (nolock) ON ce.employee_fk = e.employee_pk
        Group By t.ID
    )

    Select *,  t.ID 
    From CTE c (nolock)
    FULL JOIN dbo.Table t (nolock) ON t.ID=c.[CTE_ID]
    Order By t.ID ASC;
```

To do it I added this code in the select list:

```
    sum(cast(e.Department as int)) As TotalDepartmentsCount
```

But this does not sum up correctly (see screenshot below). Please advise. 
[image]

This is how I want to have my output (see the  TotalDepartmentsCount table)

[image]

Comment: So, if you have 1 marketing and 2 no departments in a row, the total should be 3?  Or should it be 1?

Comment: Your screenshot is missing `t.ID` which would be helpful in analyzing your question.

Comment: Why all the NOLOCK hints? Are you ok with missing and/or duplicate rows? http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ If you are going to stick with using query hints you need to include the WITH keyword. Omitting it has been deprecated, it will be required in the future.

Comment: I running in Prod. No updates are going at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Your CTE currently computes 4 counts by filtering based on department. What you want is a 5th count that includes all rows (e.g., no filtering). So you should be able to add that column to your CTE like so:

```
;WITH CTE
 AS 
 (
 Select t.ID As [CTE_ID]
       ,count(distinct case when e.Department='M' then t.ID else null end) as M_Marketing
       ,count(distinct case when e.Department='S' then t.ID else null end) as S_Sales   
       ,count(distinct case when e.Department='U' then t.ID else null end) as U_Utilization    
       ,count(distinct case when e.Department=' ' then t.ID else null end) as No_NoDepartment
       ,count(distinct t.ID) as TotalDepartmentsCount
    From dbo.Table t (nolock) 
        Left Join dbo.ClearedEmployee ce (nolock) ON t.ID = ce.building_fk
             Join dbo.Employee e (nolock) ON ce.employee_fk = e.employee_pk
    Group By t.ID
)
```

The above will work as long as the `Department` column only contains the four specific values used in distinct cases ('M', 'S', 'U', and ' '). If you can have other `Department` values that you need to ignore, you can change the `TotalDepartmentsCount` column in your CTE to be calculated like this:

```
,count(distinct case when e.Department in ('M', 'S', 'U', ' ') then t.ID else null end) as TotalDepartmentsCount
```

Or you can simply compute the sum of the four columns in your final query, like so:

```
Select c.*
    , (M_Marketing + S_Sales + U_Utilization + No_NoDepartment) as TotalDepartmentsCount
    , t.ID 
From CTE c (nolock)
```

Comment: This is not going to work. I need to sum the values in each distinct case column.

Comment: @enigma6205 Do the distinct cases you have listed (Department = 'M', 'S', 'U', ' ') not cover all possible Department values? It might help if you included some examples of the numbers and how you want them to add up. Your question is not entirely clear.

Comment: Added desired  result set to my question. Please review.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add the columns together once you've calculated them?  e.g.:

```
;WITH CTE
     AS 
     (
     Select t.ID As [CTE_ID]
           ,count(distinct case when e.Department='M' then t.ID else null end) as M_Marketing
           ,count(distinct case when e.Department='S' then t.ID else null end) as S_Sales   
           ,count(distinct case when e.Department='U' then t.ID else null end) as U_Utilization    
           ,count(distinct case when e.Department=' ' then t.ID else null end) as No_NoDepartment
        From dbo.Table t (nolock) 
            Left Join dbo.ClearedEmployee ce (nolock) ON t.ID = ce.building_fk
                 Join dbo.Employee e (nolock) ON ce.employee_fk = e.employee_pk
        Group By t.ID
    )

    Select *
        ,  t.ID
        , isnull(M_Marketing, 0) + isnull(S_Sales, 0) + isnull(U_Utilization, 0) + isnull(No_NoDepartment, 0) as TotalDepartments
    From CTE c (nolock)
    FULL JOIN dbo.Table t (nolock) ON t.ID=c.[CTE_ID]
    Order By t.ID ASC;
```